# Linux command inside PHP foreach loop too slow and never returns result

Tags: php, foreach, refactoring, exec

**OBJECTIVE:** The below is the script that I am trying to use for getting each IP's UP status. If the IP is Up it will each `13.61.28.20 - yes` else `13.61.28.20 - no`.

**PROBLEM:** I am not getting any result with the below script. To find this to be executed as this is working very good for single ip without a `foreach` loop.

**PERFORMANCE:** If I try the same for multiple IPs inside a foreach loop this is causing a problem by keep spinning and never returns a result.

```
<?php
$allIps = range(0,254);
foreach($allIps as $subNetIp){
    $subNetIp = (string)$subNetIp;
    $urlHeader = "13.61.29.".$subNetIp;
    $checkUrl = "curl -k ".$urlHeader;
    $status = exec($checkUrl, $result, $retVal);
    echo $status ? $urlHeader.' - yes' : $urlHeader.' - no';
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me refactoring this code and make this work as expected.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR:** Script's performance should be very one like once after it's pings and IP it should print on the browser and not keep loading. Finally it should finish all the IP in the give `range` which is `$allIps = range(0,254);`.

Comment: cURL expects a URL, not just an IP address. So tell it what protocol to use; e.g., `http://13.61.29." . $subNetIp`. Also, I suggest checking `$retVal` instead of output, and also use `-I` flag to cURL so you're only fetching headers.

Comment: Check -m and/or --connect-timeout options of curl.  If most of these IP addresses do not respond, your script will be waiting for all these curl commands to timeout.

Comment: Is this correct `$checkUrl = "curl -I ".$urlHeader;` @jaswrks? 
In php.info? @Nic3500